# Pseudo inverse solution of $(A\circ B)x=v$ if A is singular and B is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Given A a singular matrix,  and B a symmetric matrix, I find that solving $(A\circ B)x=v$ by
$$
x= (A\circ B)^+v
$$
gives the correct solution to my physical system ($\circ$ denotes Hadamard product). The physical system

1) actually has one unique solution.

2) $(A\circ B)x=v$ is resulted from making the diagonal of  $AXB$ equal the diagonal of $V$, where $X$ is a diagonal matrix belonging to $x$, and $V$ is a diagonal matrix belonging to $v$.

3) $A\circ B$ is singular.

example:
$$
A= \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
B= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.28 & 0.64\\
0.28 & 1 & 0.64\\
0.64& 0.64 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But why pseudoinverse gives the correct solution ? I looked through the wiki page on Moore-Penrose inverse in vain.

Comment: Why 'the correct solution?' If the matrix is singular and we consider the problem over a field, there should be infinitely many solutions.

Comment: The problem is given with ground truth so I can check the correctness of a solution. I wonder whether I properly represent the physical problem with the linear equation. At least, the pseudo-inverse solution of my formulation gives the correct solution.

Comment: It has to give correct solution/s (see answer bellow).

Comment: For the example matrices, $B$ is not singular, and since $(A\circ B= -B)$ it is not singular either$.\,\,$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix equation $AX=B $ and let $A^-$ be an inner inverse of $A $ (it could be the Moore-Penrose inverse or any other inner inverse, but importantly we know that such an inverse exists; moreover it is the invese when the matrix is invertible). Then it is easy to see that a solution to our equation exists if and only if $AA^-B=B $. Assuming that this holds, the general solution is then given by \begin{equation} X=A^-B+(I-A^-A)Y,\end{equation} where $Y $ is a generic matrix of appropriate siza. Again, the dolution is unique when $A $ is invertible.

For example, let \begin{equation}A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},\end{equation} and choose 
\begin{equation}A^-=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},\end{equation} and $X=(x_1,x_2)$ and $B=(2,0)$. Then 
\begin{equation}X=\begin{pmatrix} 
2  \\
0
\end{pmatrix}+\{\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}\} \begin{pmatrix} 
y_1  \\
y_2
\end{pmatrix},\end{equation} with $y_1,y_2$ arbitrary. Hence the general solution is $X=(2,s)$ with $s$ arbitrary.

Comment: I think we argue in  opposite directions. You succeed in showing the system has infinitely many solutions, while my situation is that I know the problem has one unique solution a prior, and the minimum norm solution to the linear equation gives the correct solution.

Comment: @whitegreen Yes, using the Moore-Penrose inverse we get the norm minimising solution (this can also be shown easily). What I argue above is nonetheless correct.

Comment: Thank @AnyAD very much! finally I found the ground truth does NOT equal the minimum norm solution. I posted a wrong question.